# Regex using sed and or grep

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, grep

How can I display the arch and version of queried rpm package using sed or grep?

```
[root@kitchen-vm-centos6-box boot]# rpm -qa | grep kernel-devel
kernel-devel-2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.x86_64
```

What i need only is:

```
2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64
```

What is missing in my sed?  => `sed 's/[^\.]\+\.//'`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sed works for me. Can you show the output you're getting, as well as the full command line you're trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with grep only:

```
rpm -qa |  grep -P -o '(?<=kernel-devel-).*'
```

Explanation:

- `-o` is match only. I.e. grep will return the matched part only
- `-P` is perl regex mode. It enables lookarounds.
- `(?<=...)` is lookbehind. I.e. stuff before the match. This is not part of the match so `-o` is not going to retain it

Of course, sed can help too:

```
rpm -qa | grep 'kernel-devel' | sed 's/^[^.0-9]*-//g'
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `[^.0-9]` matches the non-dot, non-number characters from the start of the string. This is the part that we don't need.
- The `//g` ending of the sed command replaces the matched part with empty string

Comment: This is cool, thanks for the detailed explanation and their differences. It's very good information.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cut:

```
rpm -qa | grep kernel-devel | cut -d \- -f 3-4
```

Comment: cool! it helps!, how will I print only the first line from the output result?

Comment: @OutcastG add `| head`

Comment: Ah, i can use head.. let me try.. thanks a lot @andreas-hofmann

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` as this and avoid en extra `grep`:

```
rpm -qa | sed '/kernel-devel/s/^[^0-9]*//'

2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64
2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` removes the first dot after the first "2", because it's matched by the regex you provided.

You can fix easily by making the regex more explicit.

Other answers already suggested solutions, here's another one using `grep`:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -oP "devel-\K(.*)"
2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64
2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.x86_64
```

`\K` tells the engine to pretend that the match attempt started at this position (that's the alternative that Perl suggested for lookbehind).

Answer (score 0):

One in awk:

```
$ rpm -qa | awk 'match($0,/^kernel-devel-./){print substr($0,RLENGTH)}'
2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64
2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.x86_64
```

Explained:

```
match($0,/^kernel-devel-./) {    # if the record starts with kernel-devel-[ANYTHING]
    print substr($0,RLENGTH)     # print starting from the [ANYTHING]
}
```